# Accessing Array within JSON Operator Array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to access the "Climate" key.  I can access all items outside of the "UnitFeatures" operator.

```
"Location": {     
     "Units": [
               {
                     "BonusComments": "THIS IS A BONUS DEAL",
                     "CubicFootage": 125,
                     "OrderGrouping": "0000001CONTAINER",
                     "SquareFootage": 25,
                     "TotalUnits": 45,
                     "UnitFeature": {
                          "Access": "",
                          "Climate": "NON-CLIMATE",
                          "Doors": "",
                          "Elevation": "OUTSIDE",
                          "Floor": "1",
                          "Product": "CONTAINER"
                          },
                   },
                 ]
               }
```

I have been able to access using associative arrays.  I also have a for loop that will output the information into a table.

```
$temp = "<table cellpadding='5px'>";
$temp .= "<tr><th>Unit Size</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Comments</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Unit Sq. Footage</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Units Available</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Monthly Rent</th></tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($units) ; $i++) {
    if($units[$i]["SquareFootage"]<=100) {
        $temp .= "<tr>";
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>" . $units[$i]["UnitSize"] . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>" . $units[$i]["UnitFeature"]["Climate"] . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>" . $units[$i]["SquareFootage"] . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>" . $units[$i]["VacantUnits"] . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>$" .$units[$i]['Monthly'] . ".00</td>";
        $temp .= "</tr>";
    } 
}
$temp .= "</table>";
echo $temp;
```

I have tried the line that contains: $units[$i]["UnitFeature"]["Climate"] in every possible configuration.

The output should be either "Non-Climate" or "Climate".

Comment: This is a very scaled down version of what I'm working on mainly because the full length is much longer.  So, I scaled it down to only the part that I needed.

Comment: Your code for `Climate` looks fine to me. But there's no `UnitSize`, `VacantUnits`, or `Monthly` keys in the object.

Comment: @Barmar, those are within the FULL "Units" array and I do not have issues accessing and displaying them.   Just the "Climate" key.

Comment: BTW, IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't have `id="row"` in every TD. Use a class instead. It also seems weird to call a single cell a row.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for the advice.  I was testing some things.  That is not an issue that I am concerned about at this moment.  To see what the output is currently: [broken.press/testing/hydry/test4.php]

Comment: Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/KECciA I removed the fields that you left out of the question.

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($units);`.

Comment: [http://broken.press/testing/hydry/test4.php] This will show you the full var_dump, because it's WAY too long to post here.

Comment: I get **Error establishing a database connection**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196436/discussion-between-aaron-barksdale-and-barmar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the [API documentation](https://api.webselfstorage.com/), it appears that the `UnitFeature` object is optional, and may be null. So the code needs to test for this:

```
foreach ($units as $u) {
    if($u["SquareFootage"]<=100) {
        $temp .= "<tr>";
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>" . $u["UnitSize"] . "</td>";
        if (isset($u["UnitFeature"]["Climate"])) {
            $temp .= "<td id='row'>" . $u["UnitFeature"]["Climate"] . "</td>";
        } else {
            $temp .= "<td id='row'></td>";
        }
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>" . $u["SquareFootage"] . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>" . $u["VacantUnits"] . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td id='row'>$" .$u['Monthly'] . ".00</td>";
        $temp .= "</tr>";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your json to decode with `json_decode` and it won't. Because it returns Syntax Error. You can check it with `json_last_error_msg()`. Also I removed some " , " from your json string. You can validate your json string at [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/). And now it's working.

```
<?php

$jsonString = '{"Location" : {     
    "Units" : [
            {
                    "BonusComments": "THIS IS A BONUS DEAL",
                    "CubicFootage": 125,
                    "OrderGrouping": "0000001CONTAINER",
                    "SquareFootage": 25,
                    "TotalUnits": 45,
                    "UnitFeature": {
                        "Access": "",
                        "Climate": "NON-CLIMATE",
                        "Doors": "",
                        "Elevation": "OUTSIDE",
                        "Floor": "1",
                        "Product": "CONTAINER"
                        }
                }
                ]
  }}';

$jsonType = json_decode($jsonString);


foreach ($jsonType->Location->Units as $key => $value) {
    echo "KEY : ". $key."<br/>";
    echo $value->UnitFeature->Climate;
}
?>
```